# How to provide Future to inside Providers using Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to learn Riverpod with clean architecture.

I have following set/chain of providers:

```
final databaseFutureProvider = FutureProvider<Database>((ref) async {
  final db = await DatabaseHelper().createDatabase(); // this is async because 'openDatabase' of sqflite is async
  return db;
});

final toDoDatasourceProvider = Provider<ToDoDatasource>((ref) {
  final db = ref.watch(databaseFutureProvider); // problem is here!!
  return ToDoDatasourceImpl(db: db);
});

final toDoRepositoryProvider = Provider<ToDoRepository>((ref) {
  final ds = ref.watch(toDoDatasourceProvider);

  return ToDoRepositoryImpl(ds);
});
```

I am probably missing some small things or doing it completely wrong. How to properly provide DB (that is async in its nature)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple providers, in your case since you would need `ToDoRepository` always you can just Initialized before running the app and use it later without worrying about the database connection state

```dart
Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  // Initialization the db
  final db = await DatabaseHelper().createDatabase();

  ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      // pass the db
      toDoRepositoryProvider.overrideWithValue(db),
    ],
    child: RootApp(),
  );
}

final toDoRepositoryProvider = Provider<ToDoRepository>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError();
});
```

Comment: thanks @Mohammed-Alfateh. so in more abstract words - the technique is to create `exception throwing provider` and then `override` it in `ProviderScope`? Is it official, recommended way?

Comment: Yes it's the normal way to do it in Riverpod, you declare this provider should be implemented / overridden before using others ways the complier will throw `UnimplementedError` reminding you to implemented it.
You would do the same when using `ScopeProvider` to pass arguments to widgets through a provider instead of the widget constructer.

Comment: Do you know how we can pass ref into the override value. That's the problem I am having right now. I'm doing this very thing with initializing the database then passing it into the overrideWithValue, but I am wanting to use ref in the class as well.

Comment: @TreyThomas you can override with `Ref` by using `overrideWith` instead of `overrideWithValue ` so you can access the provider ref, one way could be by making a class that take the initialized database and the ref

`toDoRepositoryProvider.overrideWith((ref) => DatabaseProvider(ref, db))`

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Mohammed Alfateh's decision. In addition, you can use `ProviderContainer()..read(toDoDatasourceProvider)` and `UncontrolledProviderScope`, to asynchronously assign values in `main` method. And in `ToDoDatasourceImpl` call the async method init() to assign a value in the field `late final db`.